# Android:how to add Paypal integration to the buy button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to PayPal integration using android. i dont know the basics of paypal integration. What type of sandbox account do i need to create?
And how to link the payable email id and how should i use the api etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a PayPal Business account in developer.paypal.com.

If you want to create an android app with REST API, download the Android [SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) and just run it.

This is for REST architecture.If you want to use a Web application which works in android/ios environment, then [PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/) will take care of it by determining the user agent.

Comment: i have created an buy button inside one fragment and downloaded SDK AND ADDED IT ONTO libs folder now how to link this id sandeep@gmail.com for payment process

Comment: can u help me in this one should i write the code or just link the url